# Export customized excel report from Dataiku DSS

Tags: alteryx, dataiku

I have shifted from Alteryx to Dataiku DSS. Within Alteryx there is an option to format the excel output which can be exported to get custom report. I am unable to locate a similar functionality in Dataiku DSS. Could you please help or point me in the right direction?

Comment: I do not know Alteryx so I'm not sure what exactly you are trying to achieve, but here are a few pointers:

1- Some charts can be exported in excel format (open your chart, download -> as excel document)

2- You can use dashboards, and export those e.g. as PDF

Comment: I am looking to format the table while extracting it in excel. Alteryx provides the ability, for example, to highlight borders, add color in the cells etc so when I extract the output into excel it is pre-formatted. I am looking for a similar functionality in Dataiku DSS.

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 0):

Based on your comment you are trying to format the cells and borders of the data so that this format is preserved when exporting to .xlsx format. This is not possible in the current version of Dataiku.

Comment: Ok. Is it in the pipeline? By when can we expect such functionality?